# Searching for a villain-hero manhwa

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm searching for a manhwa with a MC that is strong. I think it is some kind of hero and villain manhwa. The MC meets some pink guy who is the boss of a bad group, he fights him at first and joins the group later on. The MC also got asked if he wants to be the boss of the group. I think he has some kind of blue aura and he hides his identity and also saves a girl who has a brother that is strong and has some kind of red power. The brother is a hero and the MC is a villain. I seem to remember the pink villain guy had a canon and his suit looked like some suit for bikes or something similar, not something you would expect a villain to wear. The pink one was wanted and the MC searched for him but they became good friends later on.

Comment: What are the SF/fantasy aspects of the story?

Comment: Don‘t understand the question :D

Comment: Did the "pink guy" dress in pink? Have pink hair? Pink skin? A pink aura?

Comment: Yeah, he had a canon I think and his suit looked like some suit for bikes or sth. Not something u would consider a villain and the guy was wanted, the mc searched for him

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is from [Villain to kill](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/uikn3xv/villain-to-kill)?

Your summary is actually matched with the story line. The blue aura you see is actually dark blue when he use his ability. The brother one ability is fire

The pink one maybe you mismatch him with the girl MC save.

This is previous Gadam Vilzone BOSS that pass his role to MC

[image: Driver]

Comment: Yes this is the one I searched. Thank ya